# mount and systemctl not executing inside crontab

Tags: mount, cron, crontab, systemctl

Under root, i run crontab -e and write :

```
0 21 * * * systemctl stop transmission-daemon && umount /mnt/WD5 && hdparm -y /dev/sda
```

I also tried

```
0 21 * * * mount /mnt/WD5
```

None of them are working and I don't have logs in /var/log/cron

Comment: Put it into a script along with copious amounts of logger statements. However, that seconds command requires that `/mnt/WD5` be mentioned in `/etc/fstab`.